# To convert a given expression into a function of $x^n$ ( angle being a constant)

Tags: linear-algebra, functions

I have a linear equation which needs to converted as a function of x. I have tried a lot but could not succeed. It ended up being complicated.

Linear expression: $$ x^s+x^c-x-1=\pi^y $$ where $$ s= \sin(\psi)$$
and $$ c=\cos(\psi)$$ $$ \psi =\text{constant}$$
The above equations needs to be converted to :$$f(x)=y$$

Comment: You need to use logarithms. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm

Comment: i have tried to use log but to apply it on the left hand side becomes complicated that is the reason why i have posted the question

Comment: @Vinay5forPrime You and I have very different definitions of the word *linear*, sir.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a linear equation, since $x$ appears with an exponent $\ne1$. Taking logarithms you can transform the equation into
$$
\frac{\log(x^s+x^c-x-1)}{\log\pi}=y.
$$

Comment: yes absolutely right it was not a linear equation. my bad i framed the question wrongly.